# What is the correct way to add a named HttpClient in an F# Web API application?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, f#

I'm trying to get a named `HttpClient` to work in an F# Web API project. When I make the call to `CreateClient` on the injected `IHttpClientFactory` instance and supply the name, I'm expecting the `HttpClient` instance that I get back to include the settings I used when I add it to the services collection. However, the client I get back is a default.

Here is how I'm registering the named client.

```ml
// From: Program.fs
module Program =
    let exitCode = 0

    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main args =

        let builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args)
        builder.Services.AddControllers()
        builder.Services.AddHttpClient("MyClient", (fun client ->
            let creds = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"user01:password123"))
            client.BaseAddress <- Uri("https://my-service-url")
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"))
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization <- AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", creds)
            )) |> ignore
        ...
```

Here is where I inject the factory into the controller and try to get an instance of the pre-configured named client.

```ml
// From: WeatherForecastController.fs
[<ApiController>]
[<Route("[controller]")>]
type WeatherForecastController (logger : ILogger<WeatherForecastController>, httpClientFactory:IHttpClientFactory) =
    inherit ControllerBase()

    let httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("MyClient")
    ...
```

When I inspect the `httpClient` instance, I find that `BaseAddress` is null. I'm expecting it to be `https://my-service-url` since that was what I set in the call to `AddHttpClient`.

I've tried to follow the docs but I may have missed something critical in the translation from C# to F#. If I set up this same exact sample in a C# app it works as expected.

Is there a mistake in the way I'm setting up the named client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the F# version works if I add a type parameter in the call to `AddHttpClient`. So I changed the line

```ml
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("MyClient", (fun client ->
```

to

```ml
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<HttpClient>("MyClient", (fun client ->
```

and then it started working and giving back a configured `HttpClient` instance as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can also specify the type of the second parameter excplicitly:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("MyClient", Action<HttpClient>(fun client ->
```

This way it will be exactly like the documented C#-version.

This issue is discussed here: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/16422